# design pattern to use for complicated form

Tags: javascript

My form has a number of fields with autocomplete and trying to refactor so I am not creating spaghetti code in javascript. And for those autocomplete fields I need to validate with remote call on submit. For autocomplete I would use the decorator pattern but I am not sure how can I  implement the validation part.

```
textBox = new ZipCodeAutocomplete( new TextBox() );
textBox2 = new CompanyNameAutocomplete( new TextBox() );
```

Answer (score 2):

Autocomplete is easy.

`<input autocomplete />`

If you want a decorator then use

```
function autoCompleteDecorator(input) {
    input.autocomplete = "on"
    return input
}
```

Comment: I meant the jquery autocomplete like this one http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/remote.html

Comment: Yeah I did figure out that autocomplete part but how can I add validation to this control? It will be something like this? new CompanyNameValidate( new CompanyNameAutocomplete( new TextBox() ) );